# Why is cyclopropenium aromatic but not cyclodecapentaene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

An $\ce{sp^2}$ hybridized carbon prefers a bond angle of $120^\ce{o}$. It would be willing to deviate if it acquires extra stability, for example through aromaticity. For this reason, the carbon atoms in [cyclopropenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclopropenium_ion) cation are happy with a bond angle of $60^\ce{o}$, which deviates from the standard angle of $120^\ce{o}$ by $60^\ce{o}$.

[image]

My question is, why doesn't [cyclodecapentaene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclodecapentaene) acquire a planar shape and become aromatic? I am specifically talking about this isomer:

[image: cyclodecapentaene]

In a regular decagonal structure, each internal angle would be $144^\ce{o}$. This deviates from the standard trigonal angle by $24^\ce{o}$, which is *much* less than the deviation for the cation.

My guess is that even though the deviation from the standard angle is much lower in the case of cyclodecapentaene, the number of carbon atoms experiencing the strain is far greater. This increases the overall strain in the molecule. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Yes one can think this way. All boils down to consider that even in benzene what drives aromaticity is the sigma skeleton. In other words, the pi electrons are those being forced to delocalise,and not that delocalisation drives the skeleton. Of course this must be taken with caution, but it is easy to be seen in benzene as everithing fits the geometry of sp2 carbon. Note that for cyclopropenium there should be a banana character, as far the first part of your question is concerned.

Comment: Cyclopropenium can't deform to lower strain, while big molecules have plenty options to do it.

Comment: @Alchimista Thanks for making the clarification in the first part of your comment. Could you elaborate on this, though: "...for cyclopropenium there should be banana character."

Comment: @RayBradbury https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent_bond